# Fix Image.reduceRegion type error

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to follow along with the world bank tutorial on using night light data (as such I am not very advanced in this regard).
When running the following code:

```
var viirs = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMSLCFG").filterDate('2015-01-01','2015-01-31').select('avg_rad'))
var japan0 = ee.Feature(ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0").filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Japan')).first())


var japanSOL500 = viirs.reduceRegion({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry:japan0.geometry(),
  scale: 500,
  maxPixels:1e9})
  
  
print(japanSOL500)
```

I get the following error:

```
Dictionary (Error)
Image.reduceRegion, argument 'image': Invalid type.
Expected type: Image<unknown bands>.
Actual type: ImageCollection.
```

I have checked the type of viirs, and it is indeed an image, so I am quite confused how to troubleshoot this problem. I have also tried running the same (syntax was obviously changed) code in python, but I get the same error.

Comment: How did you check the type of `viirs`? Because if you print it to the console you will see that it is an ImageCollection. It holds only 1 image, so you can use `ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMSLCFG").filterDate('2015-01-01','2015-01-31').select('avg_rad').first()` to get the image

Comment: I am not sure why, but that did the trick. Thank you!